# "Reboot: power down" issues in Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, boot, debian, bios, grub

So, the shortish version:

My system will no longer power down after I issue a shutdown command (either from within KDE or on the command line, or it would seem Windows), I see the line "Reboot: power down" on screen after services have stopped from Debian, and then the machine sits there without killing the power until I hold down the power button.

Reboot works though (powers off completely then restarts).

It used to power down, and the only change I can remember making since I noticed the issue is that; I moved components to a new PC case, and added a second HDD for a Win7 installation... but unless I'm missing something, I don't see how either of these could be the cause?

The longer version:

Hardware list:

- i3 Intel CPU
- TP-Link TL-WN781ND Wireless card
- Asus P8H77-M LE M/B
- NVIDIA GTX970
- 4x SATA drives (various)
- Aerocool DS200 case (the manual makes no reference I could find to any magical thing that it does that might affect this issue, but I mention it on the off chance)

I've googled for the last couple of days, things I've tried so far:

1. Added `acpi=force` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in `/etc/default/grub` (and subsequently run `sudo update-grub`), no use
2. Checked that the acpid was running (it wasn't, but it is now)
3. Checked BIOS for any APM settingS of relevance (tried a few things: S4 state, wake on PCI, different performance settings...all no use)
4. Reset BIOS to base settings, no use
5. Flashed most recent BIOS, also no use

The thing I don't understand is that why would the restart command work but not the shut down if it was ACPI related?

`dmesg | grep acpi` says:

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=82698db3-dbb6-4ce2-b04f-f32475d522ae ro initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz quiet acpi=force
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x03] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=82698db3-dbb6-4ce2-b04f-f32475d522ae ro initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz quiet acpi=force
[    0.101921] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.166057] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.166209] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [PCIeHotplug PME]
[    0.166299] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.191725] acpi PNP0A08:00: Disabling ASPM (FADT indicates it is unsupported)
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I stand ready to provide any output that would help. :)

EDIT - more info:

So,

> dmesg -t | grep -i 'error\|warn\|exception'

Gives:

> ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [_S1_] (20140424/hwxface-580)
>
> ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [_S2_] (20140424/hwxface-580)
>
> nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -22
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF] (Node ffff88011e054248), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF] (Node ffff88011e054248), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff88011e054428), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF] (Node ffff88011e0543b0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF] (Node ffff88011e0541d0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF] (Node ffff88011e0541d0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff88011e054428), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psargs-359)
>
> ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF] (Node ffff88011e0543b0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140424/psparse-536)
>
> ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047f (\PMIO) (20140424/utaddress-258)
>
> ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-258)
>
> ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-258)
>
> ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-258)
>
> ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x000000000000f000-0x000000000000f01f conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000f000-0x000000000000f00f (_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20140424/utaddress-258)
>
> EXT4-fs (sdc1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

From what I understand this indicates either a kernel bug (unlikely) or the BIOS reporting ACPI incorrectly.  All the hardware is <12 months old except for one SATA drive which is around 4 years old, although I've pulled this as part of my diagnostic efforts, and I still get the same result.

I was wondering if switching to APM might be a workaround? Although ideally I'd like to avoid it.

(and sorry about the formatting above, I don't know how to get the quotes to work without empty lines!)

Comment: Have you tried `sudo shutdown -P -h now`? Tell us what that does. Also, if your computer happens to be pre-ACPI (windows 3.1 era, perhaps), this is normal.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response! :) shutdown - P -h now, gives the same result, every closes down, drops into console prints "reboot: Power down" to screen and then sits there indefinitely, I've edited my OP with some more info if it helps.

Comment: Can you try `systemctl poweroff`?

Comment: Hi MariusM - systemctl poweoff gives the identical result, reboot: Powerd down, and then sits there indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

If your HDD is an IDE, check if it's missing a jumper in the first two pins (master). This problem with shutdown usually is caused by this, especially with old MOBAs.